# Is there a way to get local storage object in manifest.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, manifest.json

I have a question. I have a requirement which needs to get something from local storage and set it as short name in manifest.json. I am building a progressive web app and it is vital to have manifest.json to configure its settings. Do you have any idea how to do it? I would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

Comment: There's a lot of ways of doing that. Please, give more details about your system, what technologies do you use in frontend and in backend?

Comment: @waghcwb this is for Nodejs/reactjs

Comment: Do you use any module bundler? (eg: webpack)

Comment: @waghcwb yes I do use webpack :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a endpoint in your system with the data that you want to insert into the `manifest.json`, in `Express` would be something like this (I didn't worried about security)

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendfile('./index.html'))

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('./file.json', JSON.stringify({
    description: req.body.description
  }, null, 2), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err

    res.send(`The new description is: ${req.body.description}`)
  })
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is listening'))
```

`client.js`

```
(async() => {
  const result = await fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({
      description: 'only for testing purposes'
    })
  })

  console.log(await result.json())
})()
```

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, It is in `fs.writeFileSync` line.. Rename `'./file.json'` with the path to your `manifest.json`

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Btw, additional question is that will this be added to the index.html inside <head></head> tags programmatically?